# Need to limit the number of rows in each order in following table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have the table like this :

```
| Col1       | Col2        | col3         |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| type1      |      1      |     aaaa     |
| type3      |      101    |     bbbb     |
| type2      |      21     |     cccc     |
| type1      |      2      |     aaa      |
| type2      |      22     |     bbb      |
| type3      |      102    |     ccc      |
| type1      |      3      |     aaax     |
| type2      |      23     |     bbbx     |
| type3      |      103    |     cccx     |
```

I need output in following way...

```
| Col1       | Col2        | col3         |
|:-----------|------------:|:------------:|
| type1      |      1      |     aaaa     |
| type1      |      2      |     aaa      |
| type1      |      3      |     aaax     |
|
| type2      |      21     |     cccc     |
| type2      |      22     |     bbb      |
| type2      |      23     |     bbbx     |
|
| type3      |      101    |     bbbb     |
| type3      |      102    |     ccc      |
| type3      |      103    |     cccx     |
```

Please find some way to get such kind of output 
And i have lot of records in this table but i need to get top 5 of each TYPE in same order.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT Col1, 
        Col2, 
        Col3 
FROM(
    SELECT 
        Col1, 
        Col2, 
        Col3, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY Col1, Col2, Col3) RNum
    FROM YourTable 
)X WHERE RNum<=5
```

Comment: I have edited my question... Can u check and update ur query slightly ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the ORDER BY function

```
SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3
FROM MyTable ORDER BY COl1, COl2, COl3
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to group this data because `GROUP BY` needs to *aggregate* some columns. but instead, use only `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT *
FROM    tableName
ORDER   BY Col1 ASC, Col2 ASC, Col3 ASC
```